# Clarify further the goals of each trilogy website in the vote to migrate menu

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, migration

Now that we have that ugly huge menu with explanations we may as well put it to good use.

> This question is server or system administration related, and is a better fit for Server Fault.

could be

> Migrate to Server Fault. Server Fault deals with people who **manage or maintain** computers in a professional capacity. It is however not for general computer troubleshooting questions.

---

> This question is related to computer hardware or computer software in general, and is a better fit for Super User.

could be:

> Migrate to Super User. Super User deals with computer hardware or software in general; however **questions about videogames, websites or smartphones don't belong there.**

---

> This question is a discussion of this web site or community itself, and is a better fit for Meta Stack Overflow.

(just for consistency)

> Migrate to Meta Stack Overflow. Meta Stack Overflow deals with discussion of this web site or the community itself.

---

Note that this would only be for the descriptions of the menu; the old ones should still be used in the "question closed [...]" bottom notification.

Comment: The menu's too damn big already.

Comment: +1 to make it bigger :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's fine the way it is. One thing I've noticed over and over again is that people usually don't take the time to read. Having a **wall of text** certainly doesn't make it any better. Also, the close popup is already **huge**, I don't want to turn my monitor to portrait mode just to be able to read all the close reasons.

**KISS**; always keep this in mind. We don't need to copy-paste the FAQ for each site into that close popup. If you don't know what the other sites do, don't vote to migrate to them.